# clang-format AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent causes return type on its own line

Tags: c++, clang-format

Why does clang-format put the return type on its own line with `AlignAfterOpenBracket` set to `BlockIndent`?

```
class Test {
  virtual void
  mergeOfflineRegions(const std::string &sideDatabasePath, std::function<void(expected<OfflineRegions, std::exception_ptr>)>);
};
```

No matter how high I set the `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine`, the problem persists.

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
class Test {
  virtual void mergeOfflineRegions(
    const std::string &sideDatabasePath,
    std::function<void(expected<OfflineRegions, std::exception_ptr>)>
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks like it is bugged: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55473